# Callout component get wrong position inside bottom placeholder

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx, callouts

I am trying to show the react callout component inside the bottom placeholder in a modern SharePoint page but when I click the button to open the callout this shows in the top left of the screen and not right under the button.

Is there some css that I should override in the application?

Comment: Is this a CSS issue?

Comment: Hi,  I found the issue. I was missing the ref={this._menuButtonElement} property that indicate which is the context of the callout. Now is working!